# 'JacocoTaskExtension' does not exist with jdk11 , AGP 7.0.+ and ,Gradle 7.0.+

Tags: testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

jacoco works like charm with AGP 4.0.1, gradle 6.+ , jdk1.8  but throw error "JacocoTaskExtension" not found with upgraded gradle version which is below.

```
   Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.12 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.5 x86_64
```

**Steps to reproduce** :

I am not able to import **JacocoTaskExtension** in below kotlin class **CodeCoveragePlugin**
It's working fine with jkd 1.8 but not with jdk11

why am i using jdk11 ?

jdk11 is mandatory for agp 7.+ and gradle 7.+

**My final goal** : make it functional with agp7.+

```
package com.jitendra.sdk.android.gradle.quality.coverage

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginConvention
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension

@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
class CodeCoveragePlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) = project.run {
        val extension = extensions.create("codeCoverage", CodeCoverageExtension::class)

        apply(plugin = "jacoco")

        jacoco {
            toolVersion = 0.8.7
        }
        java { createJavaTasks(sourceSets["main"], extension) }

        setupAndroidTasks(extension)
    }

    private fun Project.java(run: JavaPlugin.() -> Unit) = plugins.withType(JavaPlugin::class, run)

    private val Project.sourceSets get() = convention.getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention::class).sourceSets

    private fun Project.jacoco(run: JacocoPluginExtension.() -> Unit) = configure(run)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue. Could you please check the listed stack trace from the console?

If it contains:

> Unexpected SMAP line: *S KotlinDebug"

Then it's clear that you haven't used the correct version **0.8.7** of Jacoco, [as discussed here](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1216). In my case, I still [need to add](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44757) the following configuration:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            if (requested.group == "org.jacoco") {
                useVersion("0.8.7")
            }
        }
    }
```

You can put it inside your `project.run` closure. Hope it works. If not, please share your stack trace as part of your question.

Comment: thanks, this version help me in jdk 11